# Свойств кнопок javascript

Tags: javascript

Есть ли возможность изменять свойства кнопок только средствами javascript.
Например, создаю кнопку таким образом:

```js
var btn = document.createElement('input');
btn.id = 'b1';
btn.type = 'button';
btn.value = 'button 1';
btn.setAttribute('onclick', 'obj.HandleClick1();');
document.body.appendChild(btn);
```

Есть ли возможность меня свойства кнопок именно из javascript. Ну то есть, сделать саму красивую кнопку, сделать анимацию при наведении на кнопку и прочее.

Comment: Красиво - это css. Добавляешь к кнопке класс, а в css его описываешь

Comment: `btn.setAttribute('onclick', 'obj.HandleClick1();');` обработчик события *можно* навесить через [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Comment: Да про css то в курсе.Мне нужно возможностями чистого css сделать это. Нашел уже не плохую документацию Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

То что касается программного изменения свойств:

1. У элементов есть св-во [`.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) которое по сути inline стиль элемента

Для работы с ним все [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS) св-ва преобразуются в [`camelCase`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase)  т.е `background-color` становится `backgroundColor`

2. Добавляйте обработчик правильно, либо присваивая ф-цию полю [`.onclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/onclick)`= ...` либо добавляя в коллекцию слушателей: [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)`('onclick', ...)`

---

```js
var btn = document.createElement('input');
btn.id = 'b1';
btn.type = 'button';
btn.value = 'button 1';
btn.onclick = function(){
  btn.style.backgroundColor = `hsl(${Math.random()*255},100%,75%)`
}

document.body.appendChild(btn);
```

---

Можно так же воспользоваться стилями

```js
var btn = document.createElement('input');
btn.id = 'b1';
btn.type = 'button';
btn.value = 'button 1';
btn.onclick = function(){
  btn.className = `btn${Math.round(Math.random()*3)}`
}

document.body.appendChild(btn);
```

```css
.btn0 {
  background-color: red;
}
.btn1 {
  background-color: green;
}
.btn2 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

---

PS: но похоже что Вы сможете обойтись только лишь `CSS` с Вашей задачей, без `javascript`

Comment: Спасибо. Нашел еще неплохую документацию. Мне просто нужно сделать только возможностями JavaScript

Comment: @gena_termit mozilla developer network (mdn), ссылки на который я приводил, очень не плох